# Changing Folium Geocoder icon

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I am trying to change the default `geocoder` icon with `folium`.

I thought using something like `i = folium.Icon(color='black')` would work, as I use a similar code to change my the icons of other markers.

But the code does not seem responsive.

What am I missing?

```
from folium.plugins import Geocoder
def list_venues(request):
    venue_markers = Venue.objects.filter(venue_active=True)
    center_location = [average_latitude,average_longitude]
    #center_zoom_start= 
    tiles_style = 'Stamen Terrain'
   
    m = folium.Map(location=center_location,tiles=tiles_style)
    m.fit_bounds([[min_latitude, min_longitude], [max_latitude, max_longitude]])
    icon_location= folium.Icon(color='black')
    icon_location_json = json.loads(icon_location.to_json())
    Geocoder(icon=icon_location_json).add_to(m)
    m_access = folium.Map(location=center_location,tiles=tiles_style)
    
    for venue in venue_markers:
        iframe = branca.element.IFrame(html=html, width=150, height=60)
        popup=folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=300)
        
        if venue.venue_type == 1:
            coordinates =(venue.latitude, venue.longitude)
            folium.Marker(coordinates,popup=popup,icon=folium.Icon(color='black',icon='utensils',prefix='fa',fill_opacity=1)).add_to(m)
        elif venue.venue_type == 2:       
            coordinates =(venue.latitude, venue.longitude)
            folium.Marker(coordinates,popup=popup,icon=folium.Icon(color='red',icon='glass-cheers',prefix='fa')).add_to(m)
        elif venue.venue_type == 3:       
            coordinates =(venue.latitude, venue.longitude)
            folium.Marker(coordinates,popup=popup,icon=folium.Icon(color='blue',icon='coffee',prefix='fa')).add_to(m)
        elif venue.venue_type == 4:       
            coordinates =(venue.latitude, venue.longitude)
            folium.Marker(coordinates,popup=popup,icon=folium.Icon(color='orange',icon='bread-slice',prefix='fa')).add_to(m)
        elif venue.venue_type == 5:       
            coordinates =(venue.latitude, venue.longitude)
            folium.Marker(coordinates,popup=popup,icon=folium.Icon(color='green',icon='shop',prefix='fa')).add_to(m)

    context = {'icon_location_json':icon_location_json,'venue_markers':venue_markers,'map_access':m_access._repr_html_,'map':m._repr_html_}
    
    return render(request,'template.html',context)
```

**logs**

the /None is (I think) due to a toggle switch. Dont expect it to have anything to do with the marker.

```
[24/Apr/2023 22:21:00] "GET /list_venues/ HTTP/1.1" 200 55142
Not Found: /list_venues/None
[24/Apr/2023 22:21:00] "GET /list_venues/None HTTP/1.1" 404 16305
```

Comment: can you include the `request` argument and other variables in the question?

Comment: Hi there. I added more variables. Regarding the  request argument, I wasnt sure what you meant, so I added the logs. But let me know if thats not what you needed to see. (thanks for the help!)